# Restoring database not all rows restored

Tags: db2, restore, db2-luw, roll-forward

I have a table `EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE` inside database `HELLO` which contains 3 records as listed below:

```
EMP_NO  BIRTH_DATE FIRST_NAME         LAST_NAME            GENDER HIRE_DATE  BANK_ACCOUNT_NUMBER PHONE_NUMBER  
------- ---------- ------------------ -------------------- ------ ---------- ------------------- --------------
     1. 06/05/1998 A                  B                     M     01/02/2019 026201521420        +91X 
     2. 10/14/1997 C                  D                     M     01/07/2019 034212323454        +91Y 
     3. 05/27/1997 E                  F                     F     01/14/2019 92329323123         +91Z
```

Then I first take an offline backup using the following commands

```
mkdir offlinebackup
db2 terminate
db2 deactivate database HELLO
db2 backup database HELLO to ~/offlinebackup/
```

After which I get this output:

```
Backup successful. The timestamp for this backup image is : 20190128115210
```

Now I take an online backup using the following commands

```
db2 update database configuration for HELLO using LOGARCHMETH1 'DISK:/database/config/db2inst1/onlinebackup'
db2 backup database HELLO online to /database/config/db2inst1/onlinebackup compress include logs
```

After this I get the output as:

```
Backup successful. The timestamp for this backup image is : 20190128115616
```

Now I go back to db2 and run `CONNECT TO HELLO` which connects me to my database. When I check for rows in the `EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE` table, I still get all my 3 rows.

Now I remove the row with EMP_NO 3. This gets succesfully removed. Then I run `quit` from the db2 terminal

Then I use this command to run the restore from my offline backup:

```
db2 restore db HELLO from ~/offlinebackup/ replace existing
```

It says `DB20000I  The RESTORE DATABASE command completed successfully`

Now I try to connect to HELLO, it says `SQL1117N  A connection to or activation of database "HELLO" cannot be made because of ROLL-FORWARD PENDING.  SQLSTATE=57019`

To which I run `db2 rollforward db HELLO to end of logs and stop`

Then I connect to HELLO and try to find out the rows, I get only 2 rows, and not 3 as it was in the backup.

```
EMP_NO  BIRTH_DATE FIRST_NAME         LAST_NAME             GENDER HIRE_DATE  BANK_ACCOUNT_NUMBER PHONE_NUMBER  
------- ---------- ------------------ --------------------- ------ ---------- ------------------- --------------
     1. 06/05/1998 A                  B                     M      01/02/2019 026201521420        +91X 
     2. 10/14/1997 C                  D                     M      01/07/2019 034212323454        +91Y
```

The third record is not visible, which was present in the backup. Can anyone figure out why I am not able to restore the third record from the backup

Comment: Redo the backup and rollforward to a time before you deleted that row.

Comment: The rollforward re-executes the delete.

Comment: You can't get a database in `Rollforward Pending State` if you restore into recoverable database from a backup taken from this database when it had circular logging. Such a restored database must be in a `Backup Pending State` instead. Seems that you restored from an online archive taken after switching to the archive logging mode.

Comment: Use command "rollforward db HELLO  to end of backup" instead of "rollforward db HELLO  to end of logs"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rollforward command that you ran:

```
db2 rollforward db HELLO to end of logs and stop
```

replayed all available logs, including the record corresponding to the `delete` statement.

If you wanted to restore the database to the state right after the backup was taken you could have run

```
db2 rollforward db HELLO to end of backup and stop
```

Alternatively, since you are restoring from an offline backup, rollforward is altogether not necessary and you could have used

```
db2 rollforward db HELLO stop
```

Alternatively, skip the rollforward completely (for offline backups only, of course):

```
db2 restore db HELLO from ~/offlinebackup/ replace existing without rolling forward
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. The first command worked for online backup restore and both of them for offline backup restore.